# SDK and iOS Deployment Target. 

Tags: ios, iphone, ios3.0

I build my project with the latest SDK (4.1) and set "iOS Deployment Target" (3.0). Can I run my project on a real iPhone 3.0 if I use some methods of 4.0 sdk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only run your project on OS 3 devices if you **conditionally code** around the OS 4 methods you want to use. If you called a method that only existed in iOS 4 on an iOS 3 device your app would crash. You can do this through both checking iOS version numbers and using the [... respondsToSelector:] method.