# How to target only ios5 device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do we put a restriction to target only device under iOS5 ?

I suppose it's in xcode... but I didn't release an app yet, maybe is it in the membercenter side of http://developer.apple.com/ ...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: see these SO questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588309/ios-deployment-target
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700013/sdk-and-ios-deployment-target.  See this blog post for info on Deployment Targets: http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/

Comment: Not exactly as simple as this one, the answer show me the way to find the problem, cf my comment. Thks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode -->Build Settings -->iOS Deployment Target-->iOS 5

Comment: Ok thanks, i was on the good way so. I was cheated by xcode, it stills show iPhone 4.3 Simulator in the popup menu on the top left even if i reopen the project. But now, when i tried to "Run" with iPhone 4.3 Simulator, it gives me a good error message, perfect.